# CocoaPods - use specific pod version

Tags: cocoapods

I am using CocoaPods for a macOS app. I have compilation errors with AFNetworking (current version, 1.2.1) and saw that these didn't exist in the previous version (1.2.0).

I did some research but did not find a possibility to define the version of a pod (for example, version 1.2.0 instead of 1.2.1).

Is this possible or do I have to wait until there is a new version of that library?

Answer (score 277, accepted):

In your Podfile:

```
pod 'AFNetworking', '1.2.0'
```

Check 'Get started' at http://cocoapods.org

Once this is done, you can then issue a `pod update` in the terminal for the change to take place.  Of course, this needs to be done from your project's top level folder.  If the update does not occur, edit your `Podfile.lock` file and change the AFNetworking version # to something less than what it is and issue a `pod update` in the terminal again.  This tells CocoaPods that you have a different version installed and that it must update.

Comment: I already tried that. But it downloads the most recent version.

Comment: how can one say this pod version and up?

Comment: See documentation at http://cocoapods.org:

    '> 0.1 Any version higher than 0.1
    >= 0.1 Version 0.1 and any higher version
    < 0.1 Any version lower than 0.1
    <= 0.1 Version 0.1 and any lower version
    ~> 0.1.2 Version 0.1.2 and the versions up to 0.2, not including 0.2'

Answer (score 93):

Here, below mentions all possible ways to install pod with use cases.

1. To **install the latest pod version**, omit the version number after pod name.

   > `pod 'Alamofire'`
2. To install specific pod version, **specify pod version** after pod name.

   > `pod 'Alamofire', '5.0.0'`

   Besides no version, or a specific one, it is also possible to use logical operators:

   - '> 0.1' Any version higher than 0.1
   - '>= 0.1' Version 0.1 and any higher version
   - '< 0.1' Any version lower than 0.1
   - '<= 0.1' Version 0.1 and any lower version
3. To **install latest pod subversion** of specified pod version :

   > `pod 'Alamofire', '~> 0.1.2'`

   - '~> 0.1.2' Version 0.1.2 and the versions up to 0.2, not including 0.2 and higher
   - '~> 0.1' Version 0.1 and the versions up to 1.0, not including 1.0 and higher
   - '~> 0' Version 0 and higher, this is basically the same as not having it.
4. To **use pod from a local machine** folder path:

   > `pod 'Alamofire', :path => '~/Documents/Alamofire'`
5. Install pods from the **remote master branch**

   > `pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git'`
6. Install pods from the **remote specific branch**

   > `pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :branch => 'dev'`
7. Install pods from the **specific tag on the remote branch**

   > `pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :tag => '3.1.1'`
8. Install pods from the **specific commit on the remote branch**

   > `pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :commit => '0f506b1c45'`

   To know more in details, check reference: [Cocoa pods installation guideline](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html)

Comment: Simple and very useful to beginners, thanks.

Comment: pod 'Alamofire', '5.0.0' doesn't work. I specified a version and still get an error when trying to resolve.

Answer (score 6):

1. In your podfile, write :
   pod 'podname', 'desired version'.
2. Close the Project
3. Run pod update or pod install (as applicable) to get the pods as mentioned in above step.
4. Compile the code with your desired pod version.

Answer (score 0):

Use platform :ios, '8.0'. It will automatically install the previous one which will run on this platform