# How to change(Remove/Add new pod) specific pod with out changing other dependencies?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoapods, xcode13

I know this question is duplicate, but latest answer is not available.

I have tried so many options to achieve this, but no use.
I want to update my Firebase SDK from my old project.

`pod install --no-repo-update` this is older one, when i tried it's changing everyting.

`pod update POD_NAME` i have used this one, it can also changing the existing pod files.

I have tried below links to resolve my issue.

[How to install specific pod without touching other dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30372294/how-to-install-specific-pod-without-touching-other-dependencies)

[CocoaPods - use specific pod version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758253/cocoapods-use-specific-pod-version)

Is there any solution for this ....

Comment: What specific version you want it to update ?

Comment: `#pod 'Firebase', '~> 2.5.1'
#pod 'Fabric', '~>  1.10.2'
#pod 'Crashlytics', '~>  3.13.4'#(was 3.10.9)#(was 3.10.1)(20180611)` I waht to remove these old sdk's and need to add latest Firebase SDK without changing other denendencies..

Comment: can you try specifying  the version in the podfile against the pod you want to update  e.g pod 'Firebase/Core', '6.26.0'

Comment: Actually i want to remove the complete 3 firebase  pods `pod 'Firebase', '~> 2.5.1' `. `#pod 'Fabric', '~>  1.10.2'`.  `#pod 'Crashlytics', '~>  3.13.4'` . And need to install new pod file. i.e: `pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'`

Comment: try commenting out the three and add the pod 'FirebaseCrashlytics' with the required version and then pod install

Comment: Did the same but remaning pods are updating, some of the frameworks are uninstalling from other Pods.

Answer (score 0):

Examine the old `Podfile.lock` for all of the installed versions. Then update the `Podfile` to specify the exact versions you would like to install like `pod 'PodName', 'exact old version'`

Comment: thank you. I want to remove 3 old firebase pods and install new `Firebase/Crashlytics` pod file without interrupting other pods.